# Remove brackets from one object array - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am receiving JSON back from a web service call like so:

```
{"sample"=>[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"demo", "startDate"=>"2013-08-12T00:00:00", "endDate"=>"2014-05-28T00:00:00"}]}
```

I want to step into this and grab the id, so I did this:

```
response = JSON.parse(url.body)
id = response["sample"].map { |s| s["id"] }
```

Now `puts id.inspect` returns this:

`[22514202]`

How can I return just the ID? I don't want to have to redefine the variable as `id[0]` after the `.map`.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just say `id = response["sample"][0]["id"]`

Comment: Nope. None at all, and that fixes the issue...if you'll reply with an answer I'll be sure to give you credit :) Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the array only contains one element, there is no need to use the `map`, which is what is causing your result to be an array. You can just reference it directly, as follows:

```
id = response["sample"][0]["id"]
```

As an aside, you can also index the result of a map, as in:

```
id = response["sample"].map {|s| s["id"]}[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
[4] pry(#<Sms>)> my_hash_static
    => :body=>
      [{:mp=>
         {:msg=>
           "string1",
          :no=>"no1"}}]


    [5] pry(#<Sms>)> my_hash_static[:body]*","

    => "{:mp=>{:msg=>"string2", :no=>"no2"}}"
```

if you don't use hash this will also work

```
array = ["x","y"]
result = array.shift.strip
```